# dbeaver tab holding 'idle in transaction' transaction

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I am seeing that dbeaver tabs sometimes hold a postgres transaction ID for 1 hour or more. The tab is set to 'manual commit - read committed' and 100% shows NO uncommited work. I have also seen this not coming from a tab but from what Dbeaver calls 'Main'.

The transaction in `pg_stat_activity` looks like below, you can see the session is `idle in transaction`. You can see that a `backend_xmin` is set and that `pg_catalog.pg_proc` was queried which was 100% not done by the user. From 'Main' I have seen it being `idle in transaction` on `SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`. When clicking `rollback` in the tab, the `idle in transaction` session immediately goes `idle`.

I do not want to set a server side `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` timeout for this user. I have already set 'automatically end long idle transactions' in dbeaver. Setting a server side `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` might not even fix this if dbeaver periodically issues such queries, then the timeout never kicks in.

How can I prevent dbeaver from holding transactions open so that backend_xmin or backend_xid get old and endanger autovacuum work?

```
Name            |Value                                                                                                                                    |
----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
datid           |16417                                                                                                                                    |
datname         |<removed>                                                                                                                                 |
pid             |18974                                                                                                                                    |
leader_pid      |                                                                                                                                         |
usesysid        |16394                                                                                                                                    |
usename         |sys                                                                                                                                      |
application_name|DBeaver - SQLEditor <Script-10.sql>                                                                                      |
client_addr     |10.135.31.67                                                                                                                             |
client_hostname |                                                                                                                                         |
client_port     |65397                                                                                                                                    |
backend_start   |2023-02-08 12:12:45.098 +0000                                                                                                            |
xact_start      |2023-02-08 12:16:23.121 +0000                                                                                                            |
query_start     |2023-02-08 12:16:23.676 +0000                                                                                                            |
state_change    |2023-02-08 12:16:23.677 +0000                                                                                                            |
wait_event_type |Client                                                                                                                                   |
wait_event      |ClientRead                                                                                                                               |
state           |idle in transaction                                                                                                                      |
backend_xid     |                                                                                                                                         |
backend_xmin    |222236770                                                                                                                                |
query_id        |                                                                                                                                         |
query           |SELECT pp.oid as poid, pp.* FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc pp WHERE pp.proname ILIKE $1 AND pp.pronamespace IN ($2) ORDER BY pp.proname LIMIT 10|
backend_type    |client backend
```

Comment: dbeaver issue on github, but without a solution: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/8303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBeaver team says this is fixed now - See https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/8303